# Ruby On Rails - Make less Database Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, model, controller

In my application I have a `WebsiteAd` model & `website_ads` table where I have all my websites ads that I can control from my admin.

Currently in a page I do 1 query for each ad to database and in my view as well to see if the ad is `active`.

*In my controller:*

```
# START - Desktop ads
def ads_desktop_tablet
  @header_desktop_tablet = ad_placement('header_desktop-tablet')
  @footer_desktop_tablet = ad_placement('footer_desktop-tablet')
  @footer_desktop_tablet_c = ad_placement('footer_desktop-tablet_C')
  @desktop_tablet_b1 = ad_placement('desktop-tablet_B1')
  @desktop_tablet_b2 = ad_placement('desktop-tablet_B2')
  @desktop_tablet_b3 = ad_placement('desktop-tablet_B3')
  @desktop_tablet_s1 = ad_placement('desktop-tablet_S1')
  @desktop_inline_banner = ad_placement('desktop_inline_banner')
  @desktop_inline_video = ad_placement('desktop_inline_video')
  @desktop_tablet_b2_c = ad_placement('desktop-tablet_B2_C')
  @desktop_tablet_b3_c = ad_placement('desktop-tablet_B3_C')
  @desktop_tablet_s1_c = ad_placement('desktop-tablet_S1_C')
  @desktop_tablet_l1 = ad_placement('desktop-tablet_L1')
end
# END - Desktop ads

# START - Mobile ads
def ads_mobile
  @header_mobile = ad_placement('header_mobile')
  @footer_mobile = ad_placement('footer_mobile')
  @mobile_b1 = ad_placement('mobile_B1')
  @mobile_b2 = ad_placement('mobile_B2')
  @mobile_b3 = ad_placement('mobile_B3')
  @mobile_s1 = ad_placement('mobile_S1')
  @mobile_inline_banner = ad_placement('mobile_inline_banner')
  @mobile_b3_c = ad_placement('mobile_B3_C')
end
# END - Mobile ads
```

*In my helper:*

```
def ad_placement(placement)
  WebsiteAd.where(placement: placement).first
end

# I have a method/`def` for each ad like below
def ad_desk_s1_active?
  if desktop_tablet_s1.status == true
    desktop_tablet_s1.ad_tag.html_safe
  end
end
```

*In my view:*

```
= ad_desk_s1_active?
```

I know this is not a good practice and right way to do. How can I make this more efficient and much less code and db queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `index_by`

```
@ads = WebsiteAd.all.index_by(&:placement)
```

or get only the required ads

```
placements = %w(header_mobile footer_mobile)
@ads = WebsiteAd.where(placement: placements).index_by(&:placement)
```

Which results in a hash

```
@header_mobile = @ads['header_mobile']
```

or just use @ads in the view directly

```
<%= @ads['header_mobile'] %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Iceman. Works great :). Is it any way to make it to it does less db queries as well? Now it does the same amount of request as before.

Comment: Hmm, it should be just one query to get all the ads, and put that into a hash variable. Then you just select from that. Just one call to the db.

Comment: Great. Since I need to `pluck` `ad_tag` and run a `html_safe` on that. How can I do that? I did this: `WebsiteAd.all.index_by(&:placement).pluck(:ad_tag).html_safe` but I get error:  `undefined method pluck` Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just `@ads['header_mobile'].ad_tag.html_safe`

Comment: Okei great. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: If you want to save some milliseconds you can do `WebsiteAd.all.select(:placement, :ad_tag).index_by(&:placement)` since those are the only fields you need.